# How can I find the syntax of setting a listener in android

Tags: android

I am learning android programming. How can I find the syntax of setting a listener in [this](https://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/reference/packages.html)

For instance , we can use `setOnTimeChangedListener(...)` to set a listener for TimePicker widget. Where can I find the `setOnTimeChangedListener` in android reference?

Comment: That is very easy. Just find out where the TimePicker reference is, and in that class itself you can find the nested classes. So for [TimePicker](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TimePicker.html), the first sub header in the summary lists `TimePicker.OnTimeChangedListener`, and the actual reference to the said listener is [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TimePicker.OnTimeChangedListener.html)

Answer (score 1):

You usually do not find "how to use" examples in API references.

There are "guides" to help you though. For events: [Input Events](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html) might help.